# FFMPEG save filename with livestream timestamp

Tags: ffmpeg

I usually save clips from livestreams with FFMPEG, I do it like this:

```
ffmpeg -i livestreamURL.m3u8 -c copy -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 01:00:00 source_%H-%M-%S.mp4
```

But instead of using Hours, Minutes and Seconds from today's time, I'd like the file to have the timestamp from the livestream, so if the stream has been running for one hour and twenty  minutes I'd like the filename to include that, for example 1-20-00.mp4

So I'm wondering if it's possible to do that with an FFMPEG command?

Edit: using Windows 10

Comment: Don't think there's anything in ffmpeg itself, but definitely achievable through scripting - set a var when you start, then calculate proper timestamp based on that. You haven't specified the system, however.